# Ensure that a parameter-targeted Annotation has a has a matching Class<> value

Tags: java, annotations

Assume I have some treatments (aspects in my case) on a class that can be

I am writing an annotation `@ParamTreatment` as follows

```java
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ParamTreatment {
    Class<? extends TreaterInterface> treaterImpl();
}
```

```java
public void doSomeThings(
        @ParamTreatment(treaterImpl=Treater.class) // where Treater implements TreaterInterface
        String arg) {
    //do stuff
}
```

What I want is

- for `TreaterInterface` to be parametric.
- for `Treater` to implement a certain parametrization of `TreaterInterface` (eg: `Treater implements TreaterInterface<String>`)

I want to declare `ParamTreatment.treaterImpl` so that the following exemple :

```
public void doSomeThings(
        @ParamTreatment(treaterImpl=Treater.class) // where Treater implements TreaterInterface<String>
        Integer arg) {
    //do stuff
}
```

fails at compile time because I declared `ParamTreatment.treaterImpl` some way that looks like `Class<? extends TreaterInterface<ANNOTATION.TARGET.TYPE>> treaterImpl();`

Is that even possible ?
Is this the real world ?
Is this just fantasy ?